# jQuery apostrophes from php to an input field

Tags: jquery, apostrophe

I'm taking database information that contains a character of blah^s (I replaced the ' with a ^, so I could identify where in the row I had apostrophes). I'm retrieving and using preg_replace to place an apostrophe back in the string. Its all working great, until I try to use jquery to update an input text field.

```
$name = preg_replace('/(\^)/', ' ', '\'');
$name = "<input type='text' size='20' id='2' name='2' value='$name'>&nbsp;";
```

I'm JSON encoding it fine with all of my other data.

```
$json = array(
'name' => $name
);
echo json_encode($json);
```

This returns, in the console utilizing jquery, "blah".
Instead of "blah's" inside my input text field of which is what I need..

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I don't actually know, so just a guess because i had similar problems with german mutations (or is it really umlaute in english as well?). i had to `utf8_encode` my string. maybe it's the same with your special characters.

Comment: Look at the generated HTML. You are using `'` to delimit the attributes value. You are generating something like `value='blah's'`. The value ends after `h` (for the HTML). You'd have to use an HTML entity for `'` instead.

Comment: Any recommendations on the html encode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the generated HTML. You are using `'` to delimit the attributes value. So you are generating something like

```
value='blah's'
```

As you can see, the value ends after `h`.

You'd have to use an HTML entity for `'` instead. You can do that with [**`htmlentities`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

or [**`htmlspecialchars`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'm also checking this out in the php manual now. Much appreciation.

Comment: If the string has the same character set as the HTML document, you can get away with using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) instead. The difference is that `htmlentities()` will encode all characters that have an equivalent named HTML entity, even ones that don't have special meaning in HTML (e.g. `&hellip;`, `&bull;`, etc.). Doing all that work is necessary if your HTML character set is the same as the original string.

Comment: @Jordan: Good point, I added `htmlspecialchars()` to the answer.